# Nothing being sent to database except the ID

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

For some reason nothing is being sent to my database except from the ID

**HTML**

```
 <form action="sendmessage.php" method="post">

 <input name="youremail" type="text" class="your-field" id="youremail" value="Your Email Address" size="35"  />

 <input name="name" type="text" class="their-field" id="name" value="Receivers Name" size="35" onclick="if(this.value == 'Receivers Name') { this.value = ''; }" />

 <input name="receiveremail" type="text" class="their-field" id="receiveremail" value="Receivers Email Address" size="35" onclick="if(this.value == 'Receivers Email Address') { this.value = ''; }" />

 <textarea name="message" cols="35" rows="5" class="valentine-message" id="textarea" onclick="if(this.value == 'Your Message') { this.value = ''; }" />Your Message</textarea>

 <input class="button" name="" type="image" src="images/button.jpg" onClick="submit')">

 </form>
```

**PHP**

```
 // creates a random number for the id, ans check to see if the random number currently exists in database
 $success = FALSE; 

 while($success == FALSE) { 
$rand = rand(100000, 999999); 

$q = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE rand = '$rand'"; 
$r = mysql_query($q, $link);

echo mysql_error();


if(mysql_num_rows($r)) { //id exists 
    continue; 
     } else { 
         $success = TRUE; 
     } 
 } 

 // insert your data here with $rand as the id
 $query = "INSERT into $tablename values ('$rand', '$youremail', '$name', '$receiveremail', '$message')";
 $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

 if (!$result) {
echo "Query Failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br />\n";
exit;
 }
```

Here is the database structure http://i50.tinypic.com/14jq3he.png can u see any issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code can't work in PHP Versions >= 5.4 since `register_globals` is turned off. On almost every other system register_globals is turned off, because this is a big security issue.

It's better to use $_POST['fieldname'].

Second - your code is vulnerable against sql injections

At last, mysql_* functions should not be used anymore, because they are old and replaced by pdo or mysqli_* which can handle sql injections.

If you fix this three things(or at least the first two) your code should work or show an usefull error message.

On last thing - if enable warnings you see whats going wrong

Comment: ah ok, im using some old code that i found on my external hard drive, i dont do much php coding

Comment: still only the ID is gettin sent ot the database

// insert your data here with $rand as the id
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youremail']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['receiveremail']);
$datepicker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$query="INSERT INTO $tablename (rand, youremail, name, receiveremail, message) 
  VALUES ('".$rand."', '".$youremail."', '".$name."', '".$reciveremail."',   '".$message."')";
  
 mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());